# web2py SQLFORM grid Export all the fields and not only visible fields

Tags: python, web2py, web2py-modules

SQLFORM.grid(db.table_name,fields=visiblefields)
visiblefields is a list that contains only few fields among the all the fields in the table
When I use the export option to export in html, it contains only the fields that are available in the visiblefields but the view/edit normally contains all the fields.

Is there anyway to have all the fields and not the visible fields in the exported html file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the exportclasses argument (dictionnary of tuples) and use "with_hidden_cols" parameter

For example :

```
exportclasses=dict(
            csv_with_hidden_cols=True,
            xml=False,
            html=False,
            csv=False,
            json=False,
            tsv_with_hidden_cols=True,
            tsv=False)
```

exportclasses is documented here : http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators?search=exportclasses

In your case, you want an HTML export file. I guess you can try with html_with_hidden_cols=True.

html_with_hidden_cols is not documented, but from what I can see here, it should work (no python, cannot test it right now...) : https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/gluon/sqlhtml.py#L2166